# android : How to fix? - ConversationToQueryExtension.isEnabledForHostApp():252 Conv2Query not enabled due to current app not in whitelist

Tags: automated-testing, c#, mobile-automation, android-automation, emulators

I am trying to login android application on emulator hosted on Windows OS. Facing below error :

> **I/ConversationToQueryExtension: ConversationToQueryExtension.isEnabledForHostApp():252 Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.intelligentworkforce] not in whitelist**

Please let me know if anyone face/fix this issue.

Comment: What I dug up after a few Google searches, it might be related to the app permissions. Perhaps you need to give the app more permissions than it currently has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching on Google & suggested by @pavelsaman, I took following steps and this error particularly got resolved :

- **Re-install** [Uninstall and install again] the application
- Open mobile **settings** and From **apps & notifications** select your targeted application
- Tap on **Permissions**
- Check what all permissions has been denied [This you might did it *unknowingly*. **Grant all permissions again**, perhaps on each re-installation]
- Grant all the permissions to the application and double check it. [Refer below screenshot]
- Run application - It should have resolved error I/ConversationToQueryExtension by now

[image]